# Is there any way to remove equal sign at the only key parameter on the query string?

Tags: reactjs, url-parameters, query-string

#### Problem

I use the valueless query string parameter, but if I move to another page(routing), the url changed with added new equal sign to valueless parameter. The page is coded by react js single page app.

ex)
http://test.com:3000/abc?a=1&b=2&c&d=4 -> http://test.com:3000/abc?a=1&b=2&c=&d=4

Is there any way to remove the equal sign even if I move to another page?

Comment: what is the pupose of c then?

Comment: @JahidHasan probably to confirming any feature, seen a real use case

Comment: @wantyouring are u using reactRouter ?

Comment: @aeXuser264 Yes, I`m using reactRouter exactly 'react-router-dom'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ur using `URLSearchParams` to convert some object to query string and directly passing to `Link`/`Redirect` or whatever. U might wanna do something like this before passing,

```js
const queryObj = {
  something: 'blah',
  confirm: '',
  else: 'features'
}

const query = new URLSearchParams(queryObj)

console.log(query.toString())
console.log(query.toString().replace(/=$|=(?=&)/g, '')) // with NoEmptyEqualSign
```

Heres a few example of `query` changing (keeping `pathname` same), [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-chatterjee-88yni?file=/src/App.js).

### 1: Using `Link`

```
<Link to="?confirm">No equal Sign</Link>
```

```
<Link to="?confirm=">Equal Sign with no value</Link>
```

```
<Link to="?confirm=launch">Equal Sign with value</Link>
```

### 2: Using `Redirect`

No equal Sign

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: history.location.pathname, search: "?confirm" }} />
```

Equal Sign with no value

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: history.location.pathname, search: "?confirm=" }} />
```

Equal Sign with value

```
<Redirect to={{ pathname: history.location.pathname, search: "?confirm=launch" }} />
```

The extra `pathname` & `search` is added to keep `pathname` unchange

### 3: Using `useHistory`

No equal Sign

```
history.push({ search: "?confirm" })
```

Equal Sign with no value

```
history.push({ search: "?confirm=" })
```

Equal Sign with value

```
history.push({ search: "?confirm=launch" })
```

Comment: @wantyouring check out the answer & let me know if theres bug

Comment: I`m so sorry to late... "/=$|=(?=&)/g" regex was perfectly exactly works on my problem. Thank you very much!!